# Sql query to flter by column only if duplicate exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a query on data with a 'provider_id' column. The data is mostly unique except for some entries with all columns but 'provider_id' being unique. Most of the values for provider_id are 1 but when there are duplicates as described above I want to remove the row with provider_id = 1. There are only ever 2 duplicates at a time.

The query below lets me find all the duplicates but I'm not sure how to then select the correct row based off this.

```
select position_key, pricing_provider
from customer_data
group by position_key, pricing_provider
having count(*) > 0
```

How can I select out where pricing_provider != 1?

Ex:

```
 position_key | pricing_provider |account | user 
152894  1   2   5
152704  1   2   1084
152678  6   2   43
152513  6   2   38
152305  1   2   1121
152305  6   2   1121
152300  6   2   1121
152300  1   2   1121
```

I want:

```
 position_key | pricing_provider |account | user 
152894  1   2   5
152704  1   2   1084
152678  6   2   43
152513  6   2   38
152305  6   2   1121
152300  6   2   1121
```

Comment: Can you show your table structure, sample data, and the expected result?

Comment: I edited with sample data and expected results though im not sure how to format tables properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about duplicates, I would expect `> 1`, not `> 0`.  Then, window functions are probably the best solution:

```
select position_key, pricing_provicer
from (select position_key, pricing_provider,
             count(*) filter (where pricing_provider <> 1) over (partition by position_key) as cnt_not_1
      from customer_data
      group by position_key, pricing_provider
      having count(*) > 1
     ) pp
where pricing_provider <> 1 or cnt_not_1 = 0;
```

Comment: Yes thats correct, i typo'd the > 0. This gives everything in one shot if i remove the having count (*) > 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a where to an outer select

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select position_key, pricing_provider
  from customer_data
  group by position_key, pricing_provider
  having count(*) > 0
) X
WHERE pricing_provider <> 1
```

Comment: This will give me the correct rows for all dupes. I just have to union with all the non-dupes and i think this works.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know PostgresSQL. But in SQL server, we can use something like below:

```
select position_key, pricing_provider
from customer_data o
join (
   select position_key, pricing_provider
   from customer_data
    group by position_key, pricing_provider
    having count(1) > 1) as dupes on o.pricing_provider = duples.pricing_provider
```